# NoReverseMatch error at URL, X is not registered namespace

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, namespaces

I'm trying to add simple shopping cart functionality to my django app, and have been following [this](https://blog.muva.tech/creating-shopping-cart-views-shop-products-django-2-0-python-3-6/) pretty straight forward tutorial.

When attemting to access my cart page however, I get the error that:

```
NoReverseMatch at /cart/
'main_page' is not a registered namespace
```

main_page is the name of my primary app, as opposed to 'shop' in the tutorial.

In my models.py for main_page, after defining all my fields I have:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('main_page:collection_detail', args=[self.id])
```

Which seems to be in line with the example shown in the tutorial [here](https://blog.muva.tech/lesson-4-defining-url-patterns-template-shop-products-django-2-0-python-3-6/)

The code in my template which is causing the error is:

```
<a href="{% url "main_page:collection_detail" %}" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Everything seems to line up as far as I can see. What am I missing?

edit: Including my url patterns:

From base app which includes urls from other apps:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('qfny_cart.urls')),
    path('', include('main_page.urls')),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url('product/', include('main_page.urls')),

]
```

From my main app called main_app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^bedroom/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
    url('bedroom/', views.bedroom_view, name='bedroom_view'),
    url(r'^dining/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
    url('dining/', views.dining_view, name='dining_view'),
    url(r'^living/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
    url('living/', views.living_view, name='living_view'),
    url(r'^accesories/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
    url('accessories/', views.accessories_view, name='accessories_view'),
    url(r'^office/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
    url('office/', views.office_view, name='office_view'),

]
```

From my cart app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    url(r'^add/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    url(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving namespace in your `href` , but have not added it in the urlpatterns,

Add app_name in your urls.py like this,

```
app_name = 'main_page'
urlpatterns = [
  # all your url/paths are here 
]
```

Or in other way(not recommended if you have more than one app), remove main_page

```
<a href="{% url "collection_detail" %}" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
```

and from here

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('collection_detail', args=[self.id])
```

Comment: I tried this but now I get an error: Reverse for 'collection_detail' with no arguments not found. 5 pattern(s) tried - I guess I should make a new question

Comment: Add your args in the link, `<a href="{% url "main_page:collection_detail"  #add_kwargs %}" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>`

Comment: I don't know what argument to add...isn't the args=[self.id] param in the function definition to take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` you need to declare namespace like this

`url(r'^', include(('home.urls', 'your_app_name'), namespace='main_page')),`

For more knowledge. try this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include)

Comment: Huh, wish the tutorial mentioned this. I just tried and got a new error: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I seemed to have solved the namespace error, but now I get an error: Reverse for 'collection_detail' with no arguments not found. 5 pattern(s) tried - I guess I should make a new question

Comment: Add your urlpatters

Comment: yes I  have an app name set in each urls.py now, it all seems fine :/

Comment: If the problem has been solved. then mark the answer accepted. It helps other developers too.

Comment: No I mean that my settings all seem fine since I set app names, the problem persists